# how to load a drop down with a query using the result from a previous drop down

Tags: php, html, sqlite

It is early in my PHP and HTML career. I want to populate a  with a SQL query - no problem. But then, take the highlighted value from that query and use it to drive another query with which to populate a different drop down.

What I don't understand is how the values are passed between the HTML and the PHP, should I use a global variable to store the selection from the first drop-down? How do I do this?

Is there any alternative to using a button to indicate that the current highlighted value in the first drop-down is to be used to drive the query which populates the second drop-down?

My  code looks like this:

```
 Asset type:<br/>
     <select size=3 class="element select medium" id="WantAssetCategory" name="WantAsset Class"> 
        <?
        $sql = "SELECT * from Categories";

        $result = $dbcon->query($sql);
        foreach ($result as $row){
            $catname = $row['description'];
            $catx    = $row['id'];
            echo '<option value = ' . "$catx> $catname</option>" ;
        }
        $result = null;
        ?>                    
    </select>
```

Comment: You can use Ajax to run on change of the first select drop down and fetch the selected value, run query with that value. On success of the ajax call create new select drop down pre-populated with the results form the query and replace second drop down html with it. I hope it helps i will try to write a demo code for it if that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select size=3 class="element select medium" id="WantAssetCategory" name="WantAsset Class">
```

Use jQuery to listen to the change on the select and perform the action script with the selected value, in response update the options for the new drop down with the mentioned id.

```
document.getElementById("WantAssetCategory").onchange = function() {
   $.ajax({
                data: this.value, // This is the selected value from your drop down.
                type: "POST", // GET or POST
                url: "query.php", // the file(where the query is) to call
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#output').html(response);// repose response should contain the new select options and #output should be the id of the new select drop down.
                }
            });
}
```

I hope that helps.